# Software that automatically download files daily from my hosting to a computer into a specific folder

Tags: web-server, server

I would need a software or a solution to automatically download files daily from my hosting to a computer into a specific folder.

Comment: Welcome alexcr!  How many different files do you need to download daily?  Do you know the names of the files, or do they include wildcards equivalent to "all files in this folder" or "all files that begin with `abc`"?  On which operating system(s) should the software run?  Do you have any price constraints?  Help us help you! :)

Comment: Basically all the files in the folder, there will be only pictures, different extensions probably, .jpeg, .png ecc.. and don't download the files already downloaded, maeby a good solution could be to delete the files from the server when it downloads them, and no, don't know the name of the files.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a windows machine, [Allway Sync](https://allwaysync.com/) may be a suitable answer. It supports FTP and SFTP for remote file access, along with folder synchronizing on local drives.

The software can be configured in so many different ways, with respect to synchronizing parameters. One can set a time period to check for changes, for example. The advantage of a synchronizing program is that once the main body of data is transferred, small changes to the remote site are reflected on the local level fairly quickly.

Comment: this could be a solution, looks pretty old though.. anything else similair maeby?

Comment: I'm not so sure about "pretty old" as they have been updating it. I'd been using version 7 and only during this research found it's up to 20.